# Which way of creating and updating a document is better in mongoose.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Which is a better way of saving a document so that it may not cause any error while using other methods of mongoose such as findOneAndUpdate()?

```
const doc = new Doc();
// Some lines of the code
doc.save(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...);

           OR,

const doc = {};
//Some lines of code
Doc(doc).save()
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use doc.save() when creating a new document. And use findOneAndUpdate() when you are updating an existing document. They both don't cause any interference with each other.